# list refresh in jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, popup

I'm dynamically creating the `<ul>` in jQuery Mobile. After creating list, I refresh the list and it works fine. But the problem is, while I'm moving from one div page to div page (page in jQuery). It is moving to second page but comes to first page and then goes to second page like flickering.

But I remove list refresh line in my js, it works fine but UI come as normal HTML.

```
$('#vaultList').children().remove('li');
$.mobile.changePage("#vaultPage", { transition: "pop", reverse: false, changeHash: false });
        var parent = document.getElementById("vaultList");
        parent.innerHtml = "";
        var userAgentType = userAgentType;
        //Create the Vault list at dynamically
        for (var vaultCount = 0; vaultCount < VaultDetails.length; vaultCount++) {
            var listItem = document.createElement('li');
            listItem.setAttribute('id', 'listitem_' + vaultCount);
            listItem.setAttribute('data-icon', 'false');
            listItem.innerHTML = "<a href='#' name='" + vaultCount + "' id='" + vaultCount + "' rel='external' data-inline='true'>" + "&nbsp;" + vaultCount) + "</a>";
            parent.appendChild(listItem);
        }
        var list = document.getElementById('vaultList');
        $(list).listview("refresh");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try triggering a `create` on the parent of the list after the list is created.For eg.If the `vaultList` is in a `div` with id `vaultListHolder` try this

```
$("#vaultListHolder").trigger("create");
```

Answer (score 0):

After your **refresh** in the `listview`, you need to **destroy** the page to regenerate the UI, you can do it with:

```
$('.ui-page-active').page( "destroy" ).page();
```

Comment: Try with this: `$( "div[data-role=page]" ).page( "destroy" ).page();`

Comment: Do you have any debugger to check if $('.ui-page-active') is giving any match on your html code?